# Create dynamic picklist in Flow Builder from Text

Tags: picklist, visual-flows, flow-builder

The requirement goes like this:

- There is a MultiPicklist Field A on the Account (options -> A;B;C;D;E) and a Single Picklist Field B (options -> A;B;C;D;E)  on Case.
- When the user updates the case, he should see a Flow (via Process builder) where he will see "only the selected" Picklist options from Field A on the related account.
- The idea is to get the Text from field A (the selected options e.g A;B;E) and display them as a Single Picklist on the Flow in a screen where he can only select a single value out of these from field A.
- Question: How do i create this dynamic Picklist in the new Flow Builder.

I got so far to extract the text in this format -> A;B;E by using a formula to remove the brackets but how do i create a local collection which will be available while creating a Picklist on a screen?